# Add rows to dataframe using the string values from column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to add rows to a dataframe based on a columns values for each row so a string value of (1:2:3) will create a new column and add rows for that column as described in the example below:

I have this kind of data:

```
Col1  | Col2
1     | 1:2:3
2     | 4:5
```

I want to transform it to look like this:

```
Col1 | Col2
1    | 1
1    | 2
1    | 3
2    | 4
2    | 5
```

I know that this can be done using nested for loops, but I'm sure there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':[1,2],'Col2':['1:2:3','4:5']})
```

Split the values in Col2 so they are lists and explode.

```
>>> df['Col2'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Col2'].split(':'), axis = 1)
>>> df.explode('Col2')
   Col1 Col2
0     1    1
0     1    2
0     1    3
1     2    4
1     2    5
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this explode function. I was using pandas 0.23 so this didn't work for me initially. Minimum version is pandas 0.25.

Answer (score 3):

Do `split` and `explode`

```
df=df.assign(Col2=df.Col2.str.split(':')).explode('Col2')
Out[161]: 
   Col1 Col2
0     1    1
0     1    2
0     1    3
1     2    4
1     2    5
```